# Downgrade Windows 8.1 Enterprise to Professional

Tags: downgrade

How I can downgrade Windows 8.1 Enterprise to Professional?
If I downgrade my Windows succesful can I Update to Windows 10 normally?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Enterprise is usually only available for Enterprise customer.. so if you want to try something like this, you may want to have a chat with your company IT people first.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is No.

Long answer is to wait till August 1st when Windows 10 Enterprise is available for download on MSDN. See: [Windows 10 Available for Business Today](http://blogs.windows.com/business/2015/07/28/windows-10-available-for-business-today/) Otherwise you need to wipe your HDD and reinstall.